# How to center an image inside a list with other elements

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list that contains several list elements inside. Also inside is an image element which is to be centered. I tried to center it using the margin: auto; property but since there are list elements on the side, it takes that into account when centering itself. How do I center the image in respect to it's container?

```css
.nav {
  width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.nav li {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 5px 10px;
}

nav li:first-child {
  margin-left: 75px;
}

.nav img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 21px;
  width: 24px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Moments</li>
    <li>Notifications</li>
    <li>Messages</li>
    <img src="assets/image/twitter-icon.png" alt="Twitter Icon">
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: it's already centered :/

Comment: @AVI The nav bar is centered in respect to the webpage. However, the image is off center in respect to the nav bar.

Comment: You want to absolute position it to the center of the page? It is quite unclear what you are expecting

Comment: @JonesJoseph I want to horizontally center it within the nav element. The nav element is in the header.

Comment: What if the image overlaps the list elements ? A way to do this is absolute position it inside the nav to its center. But that would overlap the list elements if the screen is small. Will the nav always be 1280px wide?

Comment: @JonesJoseph Yes. For this example, the nav will always be 1280px wide.

Comment: Then.. Does my answer address your issue?

Comment: Yea it works fine. I just replied to your earlier question before I had a chance to look at the solutions.

Comment: take that img element out of the ul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to position the image `absolute` into the `nav` element using:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Also `position:relative` the `nav` element.

This way the image ignores whatever is inside the `nav` element.

```css
body{
margin:0px;
}

.nav {
  width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position:relative;
}

.nav li {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 5px 10px;
  display: inline;
}

nav li:first-child {
  margin-left: 75px;
}

.nav img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 21px;
  width: 24px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Moments</li>
    <li>Notifications</li>
    <li>Messages</li>
    <img src="assets/image/twitter-icon.png" alt="Twitter Icon">
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Just to add on. Since I increased my line-height my img was hugging the top. Just used top: 50% and the added the y axis for transform to vertically center it. Was there a better way to vertically center?

Comment: @James For absolutely positioned elements.. yes !! That might be the best way

Answer (score 0):

Put your `img` element into `li` and do some changes in your css like below snippet:

```css
.nav ul {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 5px 10px;
}

.nav img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.nav ul:before,
.nav ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.nav ul:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!--html-->
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Moments</li>
    <li>Notifications</li>
    <li>Messages</li>
    <li><img src="//login.create.net/images/icons/user/twitter_30x30.png" alt="Twitter Icon"></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:inline-block` to get it.

```
.nav img {
  display: inline-block; /*Add this*/
  vertical-align: middle; /*Add this*/
  height: 21px;
  width: 24px;
}

.nav li {
  display:inline-block; /*Add this*/
  vertical-align: middle; /*Add this*/
  margin: 5px 10px;
}

.nav {
  text-align:center; /*Add this*/
}
```

```css
.nav {
  width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
}

.nav li {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 5px 10px;
}

nav li:first-child {
  margin-left: 75px;
}

.nav img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 21px;
  width: 24px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Moments</li>
    <li>Notifications</li>
    <li>Messages</li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="Twitter Icon">
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1) All Elements be Center

```
.nav {
  width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.nav li {
  float: left;<------Remove
  display: inline-block;<-----------Add
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 5px 10px;
}


nav li:first-child {
  margin-left: 75px;<---------Change to margin-left: 0px;------
}

.nav img {
  display: block;<----------Change to display: inline-block;---
  margin: auto;<---------Remove
  height: 21px;
  width: 24px;
}

.clearfix{<-----------Add this Selector
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

**Full Code:**

```css
.nav {
  width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 5px 10px;
}


nav li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.nav img {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 21px;
  width: 24px;
}

.clearfix{
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul class="clearfix">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Moments</li>
      <li>Notifications</li>
      <li>Messages</li>
      <img src="http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/cute-bunny-1600x900.jpg" alt="Twitter Icon">
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

> 2) Just image be Center

```
.nav {
  width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;<---------Add 
}


.nav li {
  float: left;<---------remove
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 5px 10px;
}



nav li:first-child {
  margin-left: 75px;
}

.nav img {
  display: block;<-------Change To  display: inline-block;---
  margin: auto;<----------remove---------
  right: 0;<--------------Add
  position: absolute;<-------------Add
  height: 21px;
  width: 24px;
}

.clearfix { <----------------Add
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

**Full Code:**

```css
.nav {
  width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 5px 10px;

}

nav li:first-child {
  margin-left: 75px;
}

.nav img {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 21px;
  width: 24px;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.clearfix { 
      width: 50%;
      padding-left: 0;
      position: relative;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
    <ul class="clearfix">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Moments</li>
      <li>Notifications</li>
      <li>Messages</li>
      <img src="http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/cute-bunny-1600x900.jpg" alt="Twitter Icon">
    </ul>
  </nav>
```